# Saving a String value with SharedPreferences but for some reason it is not getting saved or due to other issue

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save marker with Latlng and two strings with `SharedPreferences` and i'm doing a for loop to retrieve it when the activity is lunched again i had another question before because i couldn't delete the marker from the `SharedPreferences` So my mind is so missed up i can't figure it out what is the issue now please check the code below and any suggestions  that could help i appreciated

**I'm Using the et String so i match it to Marker title and on Marker Click i delete the Marker from sharedPreferences according to its title and already initilized the SharedPreferences in onCreated Method like so  `SharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`**

So I save the values like this,

```
int Int,cycler,IncreaseAmount;
String testSample;
private static final String StringLat= "Latitude",StringLng="Longitude",StringDis="Dis",StringName="Name";

String SinputNames = inputName.getText().toString();
Sinputdiscription = inputdiscription.getText().toString();


dLatitude = AddedLatLng.latitude;
dLongitude = AddedLatLng.longitude;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SharedPrefs.edit();

IncreaseAmount++;
editor.putInt("IJSS",IncreaseAmount);
IncreaseAmount = SharedPrefs.getInt("IJSS",0);
//SJSS = SinputNames;
//SJSS = Double.toString(dLatitude);

editor.putString("ErrorTest","Pulling up the info is working");
editor.putLong(SJSS+StringLat,Double.doubleToLongBits(dLatitude));
editor.putLong(SJSS+StringLng,Double.doubleToLongBits(dLongitude));
editor.putString(SJSS+StringName,SinputNames);
editor.putString(SJSS+StringDis,Sinputdiscription);
// editor.putString("lat"+ Integer.toString((IntCoords)), Double.toString(point.latitude));
editor.putString("ForLooper"+Integer.toString((IncreaseAmount)),SinputNames);
editor.apply();
```

and then pull it off from `sharedPreferences`

```
String CheckErrortest = SharedPrefs.getString("ErrorTest","Not working!");

Log.i("AlertSinput:",CheckErrortest);
cycler = SharedPrefs.getInt("IJSS",0);
if(cycler !=0) {
    String Name="";
    double Lat321,Lng321;
//     Log.i("ifCycler","if Cycler != 0 is working");
    Int = SharedPrefs.getInt("IJSS",0) +1;
    for(int i=0; i< Int ; i++ ) {
        Log.i("ForLoop:","The for loop is also working");
        // editor.putString("ForLooper"+Integer.toString((IncreaseAmount)),SJSS+StringLat);

        //Here i can't pull up the info
        String iCheck = SharedPrefs.getString("Forlooper"+Integer.toString((Int)),"");
        Log.i("TheMarkerName:","Should be"+iCheck);
        Name = SharedPrefs.getString(iCheck+StringName,"Marker");
        Lat321 = Double.longBitsToDouble(SharedPrefs.getLong(iCheck+StringLat,0));
        Lng321 = Double.longBitsToDouble(SharedPrefs.getLong(iCheck+StringLng,0));
        Log.i("Markertitle:#",Name);
        Log.i("TestTheInteger:#",Integer.toString((Int)));

        if(Lat321 !=0) {
            AddedLatLng = new LatLng(Lat321,Lng321);
            drawMarker(AddedLatLng,Name);
        }
    }
}
```

So the `CheckErrortest` and `Log.i("ForLoop:","The for loop is also working");`
are working Just fine but the String `String iCheck = SharedPrefs.getString("Forlooper"+Integer.toString((Int)),"");`
Is not working when i pull up the info for some reason and i couldn't figure out what is the issue anything that could help is appreciated thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you're [commiting your changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html). You need to do

```
editor.apply();
```

or

```
editor.commit();
```

> All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()

Comment: Sorry i did not add it but i'm already applying editor.appy(); thats why the log.i(); is working just fine

Comment: @ alanazi: Isn't possible that you want to use `i` instead of `Int` here? `SharedPrefs.getString("Forlooper"+Integer.toString((Int)),"")`

Comment: Nope, The i is for the for() loop So i don't know what i'm missing :(

Comment: @alanazi Have you triple checked that key being stored on `"ForLooper"+Integer.toString((IncreaseAmount))` is the same you use on get here `"Forlooper"+Integer.toString((Int))`. There isn't a lot of magic here... if the rest works... something should be off with the key.

Comment: WTF the whole time i missspelled the ' editor.putString("ForLooper"+Integer.toString((IncreaseAmount)),SinputNames);' and i get it with an lowercase l lol 'SharedPrefs.getString("Forlooper"+Integer.toString((Int)),"");' i'm so dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your changes after work with editor.

```
editor.commit();
```

or

```
editor.apply();
```